# webapi mvc4 fileupload with progressbar using ProgressMessageHandler Class

Tags: asp.net-mvc, file-upload, asp.net-mvc-4

http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/working-with-http/sending-html-form-data,-part-2 shows how to upload files. However I would like to have someone show me the code example where I can display the progress of the file upload using ProgressMessageHandler class. So far I was able to find examples of the class being used in WPF or console application, but I would like to use it either on the MVC controller method or the WebAPI method directly and show the upload progress to JQuery UI progress bar. Can someone post the sample code of how it can be done?

Answer (score 0):

So you want to display the *send* progress on the client, by tracking the *receive* progress on the server? Keep in mind that the `ProgressMessageHandler` class is **server-side** code.

In order to do what you're proposing, every time the server receives a packet, it would need to send back to the client the details of the progress. But in order for a web browser to *receive* any data, it must first request it. So the browser would have to upload the file, and *simultaneously* be asking the server for progress updates?

I think you've got this all backwards. If you're wanting to display file upload progress in a web browser you need to look at *browser* technologies. Like the HTML5 upload (there's plenty of examples out there of using HTML5 to track file upload progress). Or one of the pre-HTML5 options that got a lot of mileage was Shockwave Flash plugins. GMail does, or at least did use a Shockwave Flash plugin for progress reporting on attachment uploads for example.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I would appreciate any sample code that demonstrates the concept.